# A doubt in a limit question which is conceptual.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Consider this question:

$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}{{2^{-2}}^{(1-x)}}^{-1}
$$

Now, if I directly substitute the value of *x*, then I get
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}{2^{-2}}^{\infty}
$$

All good till now, but here, if $\infty$ is *odd* then I get the *LHS* expression, but if $\infty$ is *even* then I get the *RHS* expression. And we actually don't know what $\infty$ is.

$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}{2^{-\infty}}\quad\textrm{OR}\quad\lim_{x\to1^-}{2^{\infty}}
$$

*LHS* gives $0$

*RHS* gives $\infty$.

Hence, the answer according to me is *Limit doesn't exist*. But according to my book the answer is $0$.
What's wrong in my argument?

Comment: You seem to be thinking of $(-2)^n$ (with $n\to\infty$) instead of $-2^n$, which tends to $-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Typesetting hint: for italics, use `*text*`. If you use `$text$`, this is interpreted as the product $t \cdot e \cdot x \cdot t$. Compare *LHS* to $LHS$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)^{-1}=\infty$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to1^-}-2^{(1-x)^{-1}}=-\infty$, and so$$\lim_{x\to1^-}2^{-2^{(1-x)^{-1}}}=0.$$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)^{-1}=\infty$ because $1-x$$>0$

Comment: @Mathematics I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I did not understand the second last step, how is  $\lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)^{-1}=-\infty$ and not $\infty$.

Comment: I did not write that. What I wrote was that $\lim_{x\to1^-}-2^{(1-x)^{-1}}=-\infty$.

Comment: Oh okay. I wrote it by mistake. :(

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to1^-}(1-x)^{-1}=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to1^-}2^{(1-x)^{-1}}=\infty$, and therefore$$\lim_{x\to1^-}-2^{(1-x)^{-1}}=-\lim_{x\to1^-}2^{(1-x)^{-1}}=-\infty.$$

Comment: Okay. I got it now. Thankyou.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: How do I mark it?

Comment: Click on the ✓ sign.